# Get android uri from directory path

Tags: java, android, uri

Guys if u can help me get URI from directory(not a file) path 
`/storage/0018-E24D/.Trash/info`
I want to get URI like this 
`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0018-E24D%3A.Trash%2Finfo`
I tried other answers but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Very little in Android works with a `Uri` pointing to a directory. What exactly do you intend to do with this `Uri`?

Comment: I want to write a file using DocumentFile above Marshmallow. DocumentFile  works  with uri

Comment: "DocumentFile works with uri" -- yes, but only for `Uri` objects obtained from the Storage Access Framework APIs. You cannot create a document `Uri` for a random location, such as `/storage/0018-E24D/.Trash/info`. Use things like `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to let the user pick a document tree to use.

Comment: Can i get write permission to  sdcard(external) above Android M  via ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE  or any other intent ,like other apps do,they just get the permission single time by and they work in all dirs.

Comment: If the user chooses a document tree with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, you can [use `takePersistableUriPermission()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)) to have long-term access to the content in that document tree. Whether that document tree refers to removable storage is up to the user, not you.

Comment: Plz tell me how. Im new to Android development.. please share an example

Comment: I have [a sample app that uses `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.13/Documents/DocumentTree), though I do not know how useful it will be to you.